# Can a local push notification have variable content?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I would like to send a push notification three times a day. Which should display various time-data in every notification. As example it should give the current time when it fires minus a constant. I know you can setup the fire-date constantly like this:

```
 notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.hour
```

But how can i set the alertbody variable?

Thanks.

Comment: You can handle your notification and change its content inside the handler.

Comment: And, by the way, repeatInterval is deprecated https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification.

Comment: @GrigoryKonovalov but i can only change it if the app is active, isnt it? Lets say someone opened the App once. I cant change the value if the App is terminated?

Comment: If the user ignores the notification and the app is not active nothing happens. When the user launches the app you can reconfigure notifications inside, for example, viewWillAppear method. The rest of possibilities (user tap on notification, notification appears when the app is active,...) could be handled by application(:,didRecieve:) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNMutableNotificationContent` class and use `title` property to set the title text and `body` to set the notification body text. For e.g.

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Wake up!", arguments: nil)
content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Rise and shine! It's morning time!",
                                                        arguments: nil)

// Configure the trigger for a 7am wakeup.
var dateInfo = DateComponents()
dateInfo.hour = 7
dateInfo.minute = 0
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateInfo, repeats: false)

// Create the request object.
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "MorningAlarm", content: content, trigger: trigger)
```